# Why initialization by assignment needs copy constructor if it does not use it

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
class X {
    int a;
public:
    X(int a) : a(a){std::cout<<"in constructor";}
    // X(const X& x) : a(x.a){std::cout<<"in copy constructor";}
    X(const X& x) = delete;

    X& operator=(const X& x) {
        std::cout<<"in assignment";
        a = x.a;
        return *this;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    X x = X(5);// error: `use of deleted function`
    return 0;
}
```

This gives an error: `use of deleted function`. However if I uncomment the copy constructor and remove the `delete` line it works fine, but copy constructor is not used (output is:`in constructor`).

So if `X x = X(5);` line does not use copy constructor when it is defined, why does it try to use it when it is deleted?

Comment: Strictly by the rules of the language, a copy is involved, so the copy constructor is required. However, the compiler is allowed to optimise it out, since it doesn't really matter.

Comment: You are initializing it by copy. Because of that, the copy constructor has to be there.

Comment: `delete` is a `reserved` word.

Comment: The copy constructor is not necessarily required. Just tried his code and it compiles and runs perfectly without any copy constructor. I believe in this case what we're seeing is a case where the in a stage (such as parsing) the compiler sees the copy constructor being used, but in another stage it realises this is just a copy initialisation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in your `main`: the line

```
X x = X(5);
```

is [*copy initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) - it looks like an assignment operator, but it is replaced with copy constructor under the hood.

Rewriting your code as follows fixes the problem, because it does not leave the compiler an option to avoid using the assignment operator:

```
X x1(3);
X x2(5);
x1 = x2;
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/dCOZPo)